# <C++> Struct the code output

Tags: c++, struct, constants, output, void

```
#include <iostream>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;


struct sphere_t  { float radius; }; sphere_t sph = { 5.8 };

void SphereDescription(sphere_t &sph) {     cout << "Sphere's
description: "; cin >> sph.radius; }


double SphereSurfaceArea(const sphere_t &sph) {     return
4*M_PI*sph.radius*sph.radius;  }

double SphereVolume(const sphere_t &sph) {  return
4.0/3.0*M_PI*sph.radius*sph.radius*sph.radius; }

//the volume and surface area of cylinder 

struct cylinder_t { float
radius ; float height ; }; cylinder_t cylr,cylh = { 6.6,1.3 };


double SurfaceAreaCylinder(const cylinder_t &cylr,const cylinder_t&cylh)
{   return (2*M_PI*cylr.radius)*2 +2*M_PI*cylr.radius*cylh.height; }

double CylinderVolume(const cylinder_t &cylr,const cylinder_t &cylh) {  return 2*M_PI*cylr.radius*cylr.radius*cylh.height; }


int main() { cout << "Sphere's description radius: " << sph.radius << endl; cout << "Surface Area: " << SphereSurfaceArea(sph) << endl; cout << "Volume :" << SphereVolume(sph) << endl;

cout << "Cylinder's description radius: " << cylr.radius << endl; cout << "Cylinder's description height: " << cylh.height << endl; cout << "Surface Area: " << SurfaceAreaCylinder(cylr,cylh) << endl; cout << "Volume :" << CylinderVolume(cylr,cylh) << endl;

system("pause");   return(0); }
```

//The output

```
Sphere's description radius: 5.8

Surface Area: 422.733

Volume : 817.283

Cylinder's description radius: 0

Cylinder's description height: 1.3

Surface Area: 0 

Volume : 0
```

Why the output is zero at radius, SA and Volume?

Comment: To help us make sense of the question, boil it down to just the code that isn't working.  No need to include the code that's working correctly.  Often that will also help you find the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`cylr` is not being initialized, only `cylh`.

```
cylinder_t cylr,cylh = { 6.6,1.3 };
```

Try this instead:

```
cylinder_t cylr = { 1.1, 2.2 }, cylh = { 6.6,1.3 };
```

Comment: what if i only want one member values in the code, cylinder_t cylr = { 2.2 }, cylh = {1.3 }; LIKE THIS , BUT IS STILL ZERO IN VOLUME AND HEIGHT

Comment: `cylinder_t` has two members.  You should always initialize both (e.g., `cylr={1.1,2.2}`).  If you only initialize one, the other's value will be random (possibly zero, depends on your compiler settings).

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem in your code at :
    struct cylinder_t { 
       float radius ; 
       float height ; 
    }; 
    cylinder_t cylr,cylh = { 6.6,1.3 };

Here you are declaring two struct variables (did you intend to ?)
Only cylh is initialized with value (6.6 , 1.3) , cylr is uninitialized

so, cylh.height returns 1.3 (as it is initialized with it), but cylr.radius returns 0 as it is uninitialized .. This problems leads to other values being 0